# Reopening project with opened xaml files

Tags: visual-studio-2013, solution

Strange issue. Just noticed, but it was bugging me for a while, perhaps since installing Update 3.

When closing VS and opening project again (by double-clicking `.sln` file), the opened windows persists (all opened `.cs` files to example).

If I have any `.xaml` opened, then solution is opened without a single opened window:

[image]

[image]

It's a very minor, but pretty annoying.

Comment: After installing community edition this is not an issue anymore.

Comment: if it is an issue, it is with mine one also. I never thought it as an issue, it re-opens from the last opened file. But, it doesn't affect anything I guess.

Comment: @DeshDeepSingh, reinstalling VS solves the problem for me.

Comment: I tried that today only but still problem persist. But I dont think that will create any issue.