# The specified value cannot be assigned to the collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

### Edit

This bugs me for an almost year. I'll update the answer and add bounty.

I've custom control, which has dependency property

```
public class Graph : Control
{
    public List<Figure> Figures
    {
        get { return (List<Figure>)GetValue(FiguresProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FiguresProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FiguresProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Figures", typeof(List<Figure>), typeof(Graph),
        new PropertyMetadata((d, e) => ((Graph)d).InvalidateVisual()));
    ...
}
```

`Figure` is the base class for all figures:

```
public abstract class Figure { ... }

public class LineFigure : Figure { ... }
public class XGridFigure : Figure { ... }
public class YGridFigure : Figure { ... }
...
```

Now look at screenshots below to see the problem: sometimes (after doing a change to xaml in other place) designer goes crazy about it and stop rendering the whole window, throwing exceptions, **while code compiles and runs without problem**. I can close this xaml (designer) and open it again to make problem go away. But it always reappears.

Question: is there something wrong on my side? Missing attribute? Wrong usage? How can I fix that problem?

---

### Old question

Ugly situation.

I have 2 `UserControl`. In both hand-made control `Graph` is used. `Graph` has property `Figures` to specify `List<Figure>`. There are dozens of figures which have `Figure` as base.

In one `UserControl` it works fine, in other throws exception

> The specified value cannot be assigned to the collection. The following type was expected: "Figure".

And I fail to see a difference what could cause a problem.

---

Here is problematic one screenshot

[image]

---

And here is working one

[image]

Despite of errors project compiles and runs, but if I need to do modification to problematic `UserControl`, then it's not showing any content (says "Invalid Markup"). Graphs are nearly the same, all `8` errors are shown for to just one `UserControl`.

What should I do? How to troubleshoot such errors? I exclude (completely) any problem with `Graph` because it runs without a single problem AND it works without problem for another `UserControl`. Visual Studio designer problem? Using 2013 Express for Windows Desktop.

Comment: is control in same project as of usage control ? if not how are the references added ?

Comment: Have you tried using IList instead of List? Also, you can try and use `FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender)` instead of the normal PropertyMetadata for the dependency property, then you may be able to get rid of your whole `InvalidateVisual` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the visual designer does not recognize the inheritance from `Figure`. One solution is to use IList as the Interface type:

```
    public IList Figures
    {
        get
        {
            return (IList)GetValue (FiguresProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue (FiguresProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FiguresProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register ("Figures", typeof (IList), typeof (Graph), new PropertyMetadata (new List<object>()));
```

That might look like a bit strange (because you give up type safetyness). But have a closer look at the WPF classes. They all do it that way (most likely for good reasons). Or WPF even creates collection classes like `PathFigureCollection` that implement both `IList` and `IList<PathFigure>`.

Comment: I may be wrong but from my experience (I've developed a few custom controls) one of the good reasons for using `IList` and not `IList<>` is that you can instantiate `ListCollectionView` for `IList`, but not for `IList<>`. And once you've got an `ICollectionView` in your hand you then use that rather than the collection itself to modify the said collection.

Comment: Next time issue appears (I am unable to reproduce it when I need, but it pops up at some time sooner or later) I'll try `IList`. Your answer also helped me to see one possible issue - I am not using default value for property in `PropertyMetadata` (should be `new List<Figure>()` in my case), it's set in constructor instead. Maybe it's a `null` value what cause the issue? In any case will try it too. Pity what bounty is expiring in 4 hours. I do really hope your answer is the correct one.

Comment: Error just pops up again. I've made it `IList` and error disappears. It was **never** disappeared before unless closing/opening `xaml`. Marking this as an answer for sure, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

close the project, restart VS and reopen it.  does it still list the errors?  visual studio often seems to report "phantom errors", but they usually go away if you close and restart etc.

Comment: *Phantom errors*? After restart (project was compiled) no errors were at first. After change (which required recompiling) errors appears. THIS TIME ANOTHER `UserControl` HAS SIMILAR ERRORS (16 this time), first one doesn't show a single error. Really wtf?

Comment: Together with another [my problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26037660/1997232) it makes me think I have to reinstall VS, windows, format HDD or buy a new PC.

Comment: yeah, i agree.  anyway, please mark this as answered.

Comment: I would, but the problem *still* ;).

Comment: Just my opinion, but I would stop using the visual editor. It provides no value. It hardly ever renders the page the way its going to appear in the program. It takes a long time to load. It produces phantom errors in your error list. The toolbox thing takes forever to load. Even the drag and drop support never really places elements where you want them.
Everything you need is in the XAML. WYSIWYG would be nice, everyone wants it, but it never works.

Frankly it annoys me that MS makes it the default setting.

Comment: @Taekahn, what? Stop using designer? I am using it mostly for quick navigation (because xaml can be **very very** long, even with [xaml region](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3c534623-bb05-417f-afc0-c9e26bf0e177)), as debugging tool (because I need those error reports sometimes) and to visualize what I am doing (to get feedback if its nice or not without need to compile). Yet those 3 things are crucial. Won't trade them off.

Comment: @Sinatr fair enough. Live and let live :)

Answer (score 2):

If the custom control is in the same solution or project, Visual Studio builds it (when it considers it necessary) so it can use the control in the designer.

Sometimes this built/cached version gets out of sync with the code files which causes the Xaml parser/syntax checker to get confused and display those wavy red lines.

I have had success with closing and reopening all designers that use the control but that is pretty annoying to keep on doing. In my experience the most reliable solution is to move the control into a separate solution and project and set a 'proper' reference to the dll.

Comment: This sounds ... frustrating. Is it enough for each wpf solution to have such project with controls or do you mean exactly **another solution**?

Comment: If it is in another project in the same solution the problem will still be there. So a separate solution is needed. Just as long as the project containing the control(s) is not loaded in Visual Studio it seems to work. Note that this is entirely from experience I might be wrong in the reasoning or understanding the how and what but this works for me. Just try it

Comment: Thanks. I will try it if there will be no other options left. Or maybe just live with it (because creating 2 solutions every time is just.. kek).

Comment: If it is any consolation: custom controls are meant to be reused, so it makes sense to put them in their own solution. (I still think it should be possible to have the controls in the same solution without having these issues)

Answer (score 0):

I had a whole load of these errors in one project.
Eventually I found that the project did not have a reference to `System.Xaml`.

Adding a reference to `System.Xaml` removed all of the warnings.
The strange thing is that it didn't cause a runtime problem.